# How do i add more images and text to about panel in Electron?

Tags: html, macos, electron, about-box

I am developing an app in Electron and am currently working on the about panel. The problem is there is more text I want to put into the panel in separate lines and I do not know how to do that. Also Is there a way to add more images like you see on iTunes when you hit about?

[image: -]

```
app.setAboutPanelOptions({
  applicationName: "Hubris",
  applicationVersion: "Beta version 1.0.0",
  version: "Build 3.5.5",
  credits: "Ethan Koehler-Bryant",
  copyright: "© 2019 Koehler Games. All rights reserved."
});
```

Comment: You could create an HTML file and add all the text there allowing for the users to scroll through the content

Comment: @Ameer yeah i have been looking into that and so far nothing has worked.

Comment: Can you add the code for the about-box so we know what may be wrong : )

Comment: @Ameer actually its also in the image, but I added it

Comment: Have you tried making a separate browser window for the about page and then loading an about HTML file

Comment: @Ameer no i haven't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199750/discussion-between-ameer-and-ethan-k-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library should have all the functionality you need.

```
openAboutWindow({
  icon_path: 'path/to/icon.png'
});
```

https://github.com/rhysd/electron-about-window

If you need more freedom, there is the ability to inject your own custom html as well using `use_inner_html`.